# Read custom projected cordinate system in PyQGIS

Tags: coordinate-system, pyqgis, qgis-3

I have a vector layer that contains custom projected coordinate system.

[image: layer info]

I am trying to read co-ordinate system

```
layer=iface.activeLayer()
print(layer.crs())
>>> <QgsCoordinateReferenceSystem: >
```

it returns empty

When I export layer to geopackage

```
QgsVectorFileWriter.writeAsVectorFormat(layer, outfile, "UTF-8", layer.crs(), "GPKG")
```

It generated the empty CRS layer

How to read custom CRS?

Comment: If I understand properly, you didn't create this CRS - it is already in MapInfo file that you use? What if you define it as Custom RS in Settings -> Custom Projections ... ? I've created custom CRS myself and PyQGIS reads it without any issue.

Comment: Is the CRS valid according to map display ? (if you add OSM base layer, does it overlap correctly ?)

Comment: @Szym its already available in MapInfo file. its crs not reading.

Comment: @etrimaille  map and data shows correctly because  i set the project and layer crs are same, but programmatically crs not valid.